# How to update/retrieve the data in/from JTable, when row or column is edited?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

How can i get the edited data from JTable ?

Comment: I had tried so many times acoording to @JB but it is not working...

Comment: it's not working because you are doing something differently than @JB Nizet advice :-) Time to show an SSCCE ..

Answer (score 2):

A `JTable` uses a table model, and that's where the data displayed by the `JTable` are stored. You're supposed to build a table model yourself, and pass it as an argument of the `JTable` constructor. If you don't, then the `JTable` uses a default table model (an instance of `DefaultTableModel`).

Ask the `JTable` for its model (using the `getModel` method), store it somewhere, and rebuild the table by passing the same model as argument, and you'll find the data that the table had the first time.

And read the [swing tutorial about tables](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html), because this is stuff that you should know before using JTable.

Comment: more than basic stuff +1

Comment: @Shanky. re-read my answer again. If you think you understood it, and that what your code is doing is what I tell you to do, then ask **another** question with your Java code inside, demonstrating the problem.

Comment: @Shanky: you don't read answers and comments. Re-read my answer again. If you think you understood it, and that what your code is doing is what I tell you to do, then ask **another question with your Java code inside**, demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Ask **another question**. Not a comment: a top-level question. With the link "Ask Question" at the top right of the page. And include the code demonstrating the problem in this question. Have you even read the swing tutorial as I told you?

Comment: You initialize the JTable with a new array built from a new map each time. Of course you get new values each time. You're supposed to construct a table model and pass it to the constructor of the JTable. This table model holds the data. Always use the same instance of the table model, and you'll always get the same data.

Comment: Try to understand what I said and what the tutorial says. Then try to implement it using the advice I gave you. I won't do it for you.